# Cell not showing updated JSON without html tags with SWIFT 3

Tags: html, ios, json, swift, swift3

I have a project, that is using Alamofire, Swift and Xcode. I have the data coming from a web url as JSON. The JSON comes in fine but in my cell, it still shows the html tags, but when I print to the console the HTML tags are not there. I am sure I am doing something wrong at cell level in the code but can't seem to see what it is.The code is below: Any help?

**CODE**

```
import UIKit
import Alamofire

struct postinput {
    let mainImage : UIImage!
    let name : String!
    let author : String!
    let summary : String!


}


class TableViewController: UITableViewController {

    var postsinput = [postinput]()

    var mainURL = "https://www.example.com/api"

    typealias JSONstandard = [String : AnyObject]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        callAlamo(url: mainURL)
    }

    func callAlamo(url : String){
        Alamofire.request(url).responseJSON(completionHandler: {
            response in

            self.parseData(JSONData: response.data!)


        })

    }

    func parseData(JSONData : Data) {
        do {
            var readableJSON = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: JSONData, options: .mutableContainers) as! JSONstandard
            // print(readableJSON)

            if let posts = readableJSON["posts"] as? [JSONstandard] {
                for post in posts {
                    let title = post["title"] as! String

                    let author = post["author"] as! String

                    guard let dic = post["summary"] as? [String: Any], let summary = dic["value"] as? String else {
                        return
                    }
                    let str = summary.replacingOccurrences(of: "<[^>]+>", with: "", options: .regularExpression, range: nil)
                    print(str)




                    print(author)

                    if let imageUrl = post["image"] as? String {
                        let mainImageURL = URL(string: imageUrl )
                        let mainImageData = NSData(contentsOf: mainImageURL!)
                        let mainImage = UIImage(data: mainImageData as! Data)

                        postsinput.append(postinput.init(mainImage: mainImage, name: title, author: author, summary: summary))
                    }
                }
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                }
            }


        }


        catch {
            print(error)
        }


    }




    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return postsinput.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell")

        // cell?.textLabel?.text = titles[indexPath.row]

        let mainImageView = cell?.viewWithTag(2) as! UIImageView

        mainImageView.image = postsinput[indexPath.row].mainImage

        //(cell?.viewWithTag(2) as! UIImageView).image = postsinput[indexPath.row].mainImage

        let mainLabel = cell?.viewWithTag(1) as! UILabel

        mainLabel.text = postsinput[indexPath.row].name

        mainLabel.font = UIFont(name: "Helvetica", size:14)

        let autLabel = cell?.viewWithTag(3) as! UILabel

        autLabel.text = postsinput[indexPath.row].author

        autLabel.font = UIFont(name: "Helvetica", size:12)

        let sumLabel = cell?.viewWithTag(4) as! UILabel

        sumLabel.text = postsinput[indexPath.row].summary

        sumLabel.font = UIFont(name: "Helvetica", size:12)


        //(cell?.viewWithTag(3) as! UILabel).text = postsinput[indexPath.row].author

        return cell!
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here change this

```
let sumLabel = cell?.viewWithTag(4) as! UILabel
sumLabel.text = postsinput[indexPath.row].summary
```

to this

```
let sumLabel = cell?.viewWithTag(4) as! UILabel
let str = postsinput[indexPath.row].summary
sumLabel.text = str.replacingOccurrences(of: "<[^>]+>", with: "", options: .regularExpression, range: nil)
```